# UISearchBarDisplayController not working well with UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UISearchBarDisplayController` which is the header view of my `UITableView`. When I click on the `UISearchBar`, the animation is jerky and it lags when the search bar moves its frame to the top. I am trying to emulate what is shown in the Contacts app. What could be the problem with how I have implemented this? I have just setup everything in IB for now(no code written).

http://screencast.com/t/HAzJRj3OgdQ

Comment: `UISearchDisplayController` is intended to do that animation, in order to replace the navigation bar, like in Contacts app, maybe your searchBar is not properly placed in view hierarchy?

Comment: The animation is jerky, unlike the Contacts app. Do you see it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had to set the option to Extend Edges for Top, Bottom and Opaque bars.